# Sencha Touch 2 form

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a popup window with a form text field in it. How can I access the text field? Here is my attempt:

```
function foo(){
    bar = Ext.Viewport.add({
    xtype: 'panel',
    scrollable: true,
    centered: true,
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    items:[{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'name',
            label: 'Name'
        }, {
            docked: 'bottom',
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            items:[{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    ui: 'normal',
                    text: 'Send',
                    go: 'testsecond',   
                    handler:function(){
                        alert(bar.getValues().name);
                    }  
            }]
        }]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. You need not do this way. Setting `xtype:'panel'` will prevent you from accessing form values using `form.getValues()` method.

Instead, do the following way.

Give your panel xtype as `formpanel`.

See this below :

```
bar = Ext.Viewport.add({
    xtype: 'formpanel',
    scrollable: true,
    centered: true,
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    items:[{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'name',
            label: 'Name'
        }, {
            docked: 'bottom',
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            items:[{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    ui: 'normal',
                    text: 'Send',
                    go: 'testsecond',   
                    handler:function(){
                        Ext.Msg.alert("Name: "+bar.getValues().name);
                    }  
            }]
        }]
    });
```

Your output should be :

[image]

Comment: You don't need the `getCmp` call here. You already have a reference to the form using the `bar` variable.

Comment: @rdougan : Oops. I missed that reference. Yes, then it won't be necessary to call `getCmp()`. Editing my answer.

Comment: That worked great roadRunner. Thank you for the explanation.